# GHC does not accept GADT type signature

Tags: haskell

This declaration doesn't work:

```
data Identity a where {Identity :: (->) a (Identity a)}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Use the infix form of `->`. I have no idea why it makes a difference but indeed it does. (i.e. `data ... where {Identity :: a -> Identity a}`)

Comment: This should probably be reported as a bug if it hasn't been already.

Comment: @qu4ntumcpa: the difference is that signatures in GADT constructor declarations may involve strictness annotations (`!`), which isn't allowed in any other place. I suspect GHC has two separate grammars for GADT type signatures and other type signatures. Also, I can kind of imagine some (weak!) arguments that constructors aren't really functions, and that the prefix syntax `(->)` kind of suggests you can freely generalize over it (which is not true, again because of `!`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as of GHC 7.8, **if you turn on GADT support, then your code typechecks and does what you'd expect**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Identity a where {Identity :: (->) a (Identity a)}
```

resulting in:

```
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ» :i Identity
data Identity a = Identity a    -- Defined at foo.hs:2:1
```